# OpenSUSE 15.0 LEAP pulseaudio unable to detect bluetooth speaker

Tags: bluetooth, opensuse, pulseaudio, speaker

I would like to stream my music through my Bluetooth speaker but PulseAudio can't see the speaker. When I open the sound settings (`pavucontrol`) I can't change the output device to my speaker since it's not displayed.

**What I already checked**

- The speaker is paired and connected through the Bluetooth interface in GNOME. I verified the connection using the `bluetoothctl` tool and made sure that the device is connected and trusted by OpenSUSE.
- I checked if PulseAudio can see the device through the command line using `pactl list sources short` and `pactl list sinks short` and it's not there either.
- I verified if PulseAudio has the right Bluetooth addon installed and it has.
- Removing the configuration in `~/.config/pulse` doesn't help
- This question: [Pulseaudio not detecting bluetooth headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580155/pulseaudio-not-detecting-bluetooth-headset) couldn't help me either.

It worked a couple months ago without any issue but now it doesn't. Any advice to force PulseAudio to recognize my Bluetooth speaker?

**Setup:**

- UE Boom Bluetooth speaker
- GNOME OpenSUSE Leap 15.0
- Pulseaudio 11.1
- BlueZ 5.48

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these steps to resolve the bluetooth audio issue on Opensuse Linux- These would work in ubuntu and other linux too. I am running on Opensuse linux 15.

First comment out the line 
   `load-module module-bluetooth-discover`
by editing the
   `sudo vim /etc/pulse/default.pa`

Now you would need to reboot after this change is done. After rebooting,
we configure the `bluetoothctl`  by running the following sequence of commands in a terminal:

```
>  pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
>  bluetoothctl
>> power on
>> agent on
>> default-agent
>> discoverable on
>> scan on
```

scanon will return with the name of the bluetooth speaker along with a code in the format '11:11:11:11:11:11' - thats ur bluetoooth speakers id. Note that down and use it in the next command trust and connect.

```
>> trust 11:11:11:11:11:11
>> connect 11:11:11:11:11:11
>> scan off
```

- Do not close this terminal.

And these are all thats required to connect to a bluetooth speaker/headphone.
YOu can put the above in  a script say - connectbluettooth.sh and run it everytime you login.

Last step  change the speakers settings, your applications uses by running the below command:-

```
pavucontrol - Change the default audio device to the bluetooth speaker.
```

You can see my bluetooth speaker - 'Juarez' set in the pavucontrol tool in the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot - with Juareze bluetooth speakers]